# In Careers 2.0, when you click on a job to see its details, you lose the sorting method

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

In Careers 2.0, when you click on a job to see its details, and then navigate back to the job list, the sorting method reverts to "search relevance" even if you have chosen another sorting method.  The chosen sorting method should be retained.

Comment: What search terms are you using? And what listing? I'm currently unable to replicate

Comment: Keyword Android, clicked on remote, clicked on Search, chose sort by date posted. Clicked on first job to go to job details.  Clicked on browser back button.  List is now sorted by Search relevance.

Comment: Thanks, was able to duplicate it. We'll get somebody on it.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed and will be out shortly.